# Not Fetching All Data From MySQL (java)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I was writing a method that retrieves information on my updates in a game and so far it retrieved all the information needed for revision 1.0. I proceeded to input 1.1 and it came back with an empty string.

```
public String getRevision(float revision, String revisionName) {
    try {
        String txt = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t#e---===Revision Log "+revision+"===---#n\r\n\r\n";
        Connection con = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT information FROM revisions_log WHERE revisionName = ? AND revision = ?");
        ps.setString(1,  revisionName);
        ps.setFloat(2, revision);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            txt += rs.getString("information") + "\r\n";
        }
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        return txt;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return "No logs were found!";
}
```

The db in the database is set with a string for its revisionName and a float for its revisions. I also definitely updated the DB with the correct revision number as well.

Here:

[image: Image of DB]

Query:

```
SELECT information FROM maplesolaxia.revisions_log WHERE revisionName = "prealpha" AND revision = 1.1;
```

Running the SAME query but with 1.0 instead works.

Here's how my table is set up.
[image]

Comment: Can you run the query in the database and show us the rows that you think should be fetched?

Comment: Okay, I made the changes you asked for.

Comment: I guess problem with `float` type for `revision` column. Alter it to `varchar` e.g. It gives you more flexibiity in future.

Comment: @Xari Just to be clear, the query that you posted does not return any rows right?

Comment: It returns nothing. I tried setting revision's type to DECIMAL(3,1) and that seemed to do the job though!

Comment: That is because `1.1` is not exact in floating point, but it is in `decimal(3,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a weird solution, but I changed the data value of "revision" from FLOAT to DECIMAL(3,1) and it seemed to work.